# Allowing only HTTPS POST requests using .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, post, mod-rewrite, https

I'm trying to block all HTTP POST requests in my root folder but allow HTTPS POST. I'm dealing with a huge volume of POST requests which are decimating my server bandwidth, but they are all HTTP.  When actual customers come to the website POST actions are required (login, etc) but they are all done on HTTPS pages. Can I weed out the offending requests and allow only HTTPS POST actions? Using the following I'm able to block:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127.0.0.1   
RewriteRule ^ / [F]
```

Then tried this to allow HTTPS:

```
#if https on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ / [L] 

#else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127.0.0.1   
RewriteRule ^ / [F]
```

Which returns a 500 internal server error. Note that legit POST requests do originate in the root so I can't just add a special .htaccess in a subfolder which allows POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block all `HTTP POST` requests like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
# allow localhost
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127\.0\.0\.1$   
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```